# Looking for theories/references about how social conventions are formed and followed

Tags: sociology, social-ethics, social-epistemology, social-contract, normativity

Social changes happen all the time. Sometimes changes lead to conventions. Certain ways of living, certain lifestyles, certain regulations become conventional. People follow them without questioning them, even when they are unreasonable, unpractical, or even nonsensical.

I am looking for theories that explain such social phenomenon.

Comment: Perhaps more of a Psychology question?

Comment: Your question is very broad and there are innumerable references. To look for "causes" and "models" of social conventions would be the topic of social sciences, which date from the 19th century.  I would suggest that good search terms might be "norms"  and "ideology," both of which have massive literatures. Anthropology would also be a sources of models, such as the structuralism of Claude Levi-Strauss. But there are also biological approaches, so really no end to it.

Comment: Sociology, e.g. Norbert Elias' works.